# Displaying Real-time Data from Arduino IDE to Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, arduino

I am new to Django. Is there a possible way to display the value from the Arduino IDE to Django in real time? The data that displays in the inserted coins came from Arduino, but it does not automatically change unless you refresh the site.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import serial


def home (request):
    return render(request, 'home.html' )
    
 
def usb (request):
    try:
        arduino = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
        data = arduino.readline().decode().strip()
        arduino.close()
        
    except Exception as e:
        data = f"Error communicating with Arduino: {str(e)}"
    return render(request, 'usb.html', {'data' : data})   
    

def nfc (request):
    return render(request, 'nfc.html')

def bluetooth (request):
    return render(request, 'bluetooth.html')
```

usb.html

```
 <div class="estimated-price">
                    <label>Inserted Coins:</label>
                    <span id="inserted-coins">₱{{data}}</span>
                </div>
```

The data that displays in the inserted coins came from the arduino but it does not change automatically, i also need to refresh the page in order to update the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV7RW.png)

Is there a way to display the data in real-time without refreshing the file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That is how the HTTP works, as it is request response model

there are two ways to achieve refresh real time as I know:

1. send ajax request every `n` seconds (i.e. polling) and put that data in HTML page
2. implement websocket and update HTML through it

If your data is small and not much processing is required then proceed with option 1 which is easier to implement. although it won't be real time, but `n` can be set to 1s or less depending on use case

on contrast of it, if processing is higher on each received request then option 2 is better